# Reasons for failure in Discord bot sending DM users

Tags: php, discord

So I've written a bot. That's working. I'm not using an existing library, I assembled my own using the API documentation.

I managed to DM myself:

```
// representative code - real thing uses higher-level functions like Discord::createDM()
// but for "MCVE" reasons this is just to show the API calls being made.
$dm = Discord::api("POST", "/users/@me/channels",
    ["recipient_id"=>Discord::KNOWN_USERS['Niet']]
);
Discord::api("POST", "/channels/".$dm->id."/messages",
    ["content"=>"Hello World!"]
);
```

Works just fine. However, I tried to have it DM someone else, and got a 403 Forbidden error with the message "50007 Cannot send messages to this user"

I would like for the bot to be able to DM guild members, either in response to commands (rather than having a separate `#bot-commands` channel) or in response to auto-moderation (rather than publicly calling them out, which kind of defeats the purpose of deleting offending messages)

However, if the bot can't send these messages, then that's a bit of a problem.

What are the possible causes of not being able to send messages to a specific user, and how might I go about resolving them?

Or should I just give up and just use a `#bot-messages` channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely these users have chosen not to receive DMs. You can choose to only allow friends to send them to you, then opt-in/out of users on specific servers being able to DM you (click on the server name I think, then Privacy)

Not much you can do about this except asking them to allow DMs from your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to (finally) find where to get dev help for Discord specifically, and they confirmed this to be the case. However they also mentioned that if a user DMs a bot, then the bot may freely reply until the DM is closed by either side.